# Why does Windows 10 allow consuming all memory without limit?

Tags: windows-10, memory, security, memory-management

I wrote the silliest program possible in C++ compiled with g++ to test my OS:

```cpp
int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        new int;
    }
}
```

Out of pure curiousity, I wanted to find out, how Windows would respond, to a program, relentlessly allocating memory. I expected it would crash at some point or Windows would intervene, and release all memory. To my surprise, it didn't instead Windows just let it run, rendering the whole PC unusable. The taskmanager could still display some changes, while my 32 GB of RAM were completly used, until it froze. Then, nothing would work. I could still use my mouse, well I could move it every 20 or 30 seconds or so for one frame. CTRL-C didn't work, though I didn't know if it recognized me tabbing out of the taskmanager and into the comand line earlier. When I noticed that my SSD was under heavy usage (the LED was allways on) I decided what's best for my harddrive: A hardreset... Which begs the question:

Why does Windows 10 allow a program to indefinetly consume all ressources and let it render the PC completly unusable?

One would think a well written OS - how would Linux respond? - would have some security measures in place for preventing a program to just consume all ressources. I recognize there might be usages where it is completly nescessary to use all available ressources, but should it be just available via a simple `malloc` (or in this case `new`)? Or is there just an issue with my system?

Note: I strongly advise against the execution of the program from above, as it may result in a hard crash.

Comment: All operating systems will assume that you know what you are doing and are not just wasting memory for the sake of it. They all have things like virtual memory and swap files so that programs can use more memory than is physically available. Just allocating memory is not a failure condition of any program and operating systems cannot protect users from doing stupid things.

Comment: Further, your system does not "hard crash". It is still working hard at allocating all the memory you asked it to. Nothing crashed, just continually allocating memory. Then if you finally do kill the program it will have to spend a lot of time freeing up that memory.

Comment: If you compiled your program as a 32-bit executable then you may well see it crash, somewhere between 2 and 4GB of ram as it exhausted the amount of memory addressable in a 32 bit system. A 64 bit executable can address a significantly larger amount of memory.

Comment: And a question for you: on an operating system that has access to large amounts of memory and can make use of virtual memory systems to use hard drives and ssd storage to act as a substitute for for physical RAM, how do you expect the operating system to know the difference between programs that legitimately *need* large amounts of memory and programs that blindly allocate all the memory it can because the programmer wrote it to do that. Most *real* programs can deal with the problem because they do real work in between memory allocations.

Comment: For comparison: in my Linux (specifically Kubuntu 22.10, kernel 5.19, quite standard setup) the program eventually gets killed by the OOM killer. The fluency of other programs (including my desktop environment) is somewhat affected once the physical memory gets full and swapping starts. Nevertheless nothing really bad happens, the OS is usable. After the OOM killer kills the process, everything else continues normally. I haven't tested, but I can imagine if a legitimate process takes more than 1/2 memory and your program strikes, the OOM killer may kill the legitimate process first.

Comment: Side note: in Linux [`firejail`](https://firejail.wordpress.com) is a wrapper able to limit such things. Here it will be like `firejail --quiet --noprofile --rlimit-as=4g ./a.out`. No root access needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because allocating memory is not something that is considered "wrong" or any kind of illegal operation in computing. Every modern operating system allows the use of [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) where physical memory can be written to disk and so use far more memory than is physically available.

What you have done is not considered a fault by the computer. Programmers have been writing programs that either accidentally or on purpose leaked memory and caused these kinds of "[denial of service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)" issues since the beginning of computing.

What you have stumbled upon is the simplest form of "memory bomb" akin to a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) that runs and quickly consumes system resources until the system is rendered useless.

In the past on 32-bit systems you would have been limited to allocating between 2 and 4GB of RAM in a single process before you hit the memory limit and further allocations would fail, but in practical terms you would see the same problem. Any system with less RAM than you are trying to allocate will continue filling RAM, pushing that RAM out to the page file when RAM is full and then carry on allocating more RAM. On a modern system with  more than 4GB of real RAM running a 32bit program that does what you are doing will quickly hit the 32bit limit of up to 4GB and will then fail to allocate more memory. A 64 bit program will be able to allocate more memory than is physically available.

But because of the extreme memory pressure (that you are causing) the system is spending far more time pushing RAM out to disk than any other operation, with the result that your hard disk light comes on permanently and your system is effectively unusable.

There are some operating system methods to limit memory allowed to be allocated, but they tend to be used more in multi-user systems in order to prevent one user or program from denying service to other users. As an example there is [Linux `cgroups`](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2022/overcoming-challenges-with-linux-cgroups-memory-accounting). These systems are not often in place or set up for "normal" computers because the only denial a user can trigger is against themselves and the solution is often simply rebooting the system and telling the user not to do it again.

What you are seeing is not any kind of crash or failure, it is 100% operator error and the system operating working as designed.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanations. I have some follow-up comments questions.
Firstly, a program could be forced to make a syscall to ask the system to exceed a sensible allocation limit. This way the user could know in advance, that the system may become completly unusable.
Additionally, what would happen, if I'd disable virtual memory? Would it then simply crash? Would a program with virtual memory also crash at some point or does the OS extend the memory indefinetly, as long as there is space on my hard disk?

Comment: Lastly, why is it the operators error, not the programmers fault? As long as the operator doesn't know in advance that a program is gonna leak memory indefinetly, they couldn't do anything about it. Or are there any best practices, which would prevent this kind of denial of service?

Comment: @Sewbacca if you disable the swap file (virtual memory can never be disabled) then yes you will hit memory limits and your program will either crash or halt as no longer being able to allocate memory, likely long before actually running out of RAM due to the way Windows handles memory. By default Windows allows the swap file to grow up to the size of the disk it is on, if you limit the swap file to (say) 4GB then you will again hit the limit some time after filling your physical RAM. The larger the swap file is allowed to be the longer your program will keep going.

Comment: You *could* have some method where programs must pre-define how much memory they want or should be allowed, but this places artificial restrictions on how they work that can annoy people using them at edge cases and could overcomplicate coding that should be simple when trying to handle those cases. Java kinda does this and it's a hassle of command line switches to have to deal with when you need to change it.

Comment: It is operator (the person who wrote the program) error because programmers should know about memory leaks and how to protect against them. The OS can give you all the protection in the world but bad programmers will always find a way to break them, the OS can only do so much to protect people from themselves. It is trying to make things work and give people the tools to do their job, not to police and prevent every possible thing from working. It is trying to make a balance of performance and features, not assuming that everyone needs their hands held every step of the way.

Comment: In other words: you are not a baby, Windows is not a babysitter.